# Defining material scripts in gazebo 1.9

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to load my gazebo material scripts in gazebo 1.9 together with the gazebo_ros bridge. I'm not sure what is the right way to extend the resource_path. The export gazebo_media_path statements in the package.xml files don't seem to work. When manually creating the GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH variable the setup.sh file of the gazebo installation overwrites the environment variable I set. Copying the material scripts manually to /usr/share/gazebo1-9/... works fine, but this is only a hack.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4160/defining-material-scripts-in-gazebo-1.9/) by [abubeck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/462/abubeck/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for your answer. I fixed it now for my installation. I did the following 2 mistakes:

1.) I used  `<gazebo gazebo_media_path .../>` instead of  `<gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path .../>` in my package.xml

2.) You have to define a `<run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>` to get the export statement working.

The `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` unfortunally cannot be set manually because the script `/usr/share/gazebo-1.9/setup.sh` overwrites the variable.

---

Originally posted by [abubeck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/462/abubeck/) with karma: 16 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

adding this to my `ROBOT_gazebo` package.xml worked fine

```
<export>
    <gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path="/your/resource/path"/>
  </export>
```

if it does not work for you can
can't you try export it extending the old values (for example at the end of your .bashrc or or the setup.sh file):

```
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH:</your/path>
```

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1